# routing help in Txroutes library

Tags: url, routes, twisted

I need to route the following to a  function : 
http://www.example.com/docs/?key1=value1&key2=value2

And the route code for it is

dispatcher.connect(name='xyz', route='/docs/{item}', controller=c, action='docs')

so, can you help me with the “route” part as in what should come there so for an incoming  request the action gets called.

As in how to relate  route='/docs/{item}' and /docs/?key1=value1&key2=value2

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET request (/docs/) followed by a query string (?key1=value1&key2=value2). You'd use Twisted's normal facilities for accessing the query string.

```
    def docs(self, request):
        return '<html><body>Got %s args</body></html>' % request.args
```

to retrieve from the array use request.args['key1'][0] to get 'value1'.